# LibGit2Sharp throws an exception while committing changes

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I created an application that checks in a file to Git to measure its performance. It works find on my machine.

```
private void Commit()
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(GIT_PATH))
    {               
        repo.Index.Stage(GIT_PATH);

        var commitMessage = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Resources.GitCommittingMessage, DateTime.Now);
        var author = new Signature(this.credentials.Username, "", DateTime.Now);
        repo.Commit(commitMessage, author);
    }
}
```

It throws an error when running on the other machine. The exception message is:

```
Can not find Name or Email setting of the current user in Git configuration.
```

After I got the message, I checked if git config --global user.name was set and it was. I checked by running `git config --global user.name` and it printed out the username.

What did I do wrong here? How to fix it?

**Update**
Below is working code, just added the committer and use the overload method like [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23236098/53261).

```
var commitMessage = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Resources.GitCommittingMessage, DateTime.Now);
var author = new Signature(this.credentials.Username, "", DateTime.Now);
var committer = new Signature(this.credentials.Username, "", DateTime.Now);
repo.Commit(commitMessage, author, committer);
```

Comment: Sorry to ask an obvious question, but did you also check for **user.email**?

Comment: @msound Yes, I did and it was null. The user I have is a Git user and it doesn't have an email account.

Comment: That field doesn't need to point to a real e-mail address. Any content is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[overload](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/RepositoryExtensions.cs#L215-L231)** that you're using will build a `Signature` for the Committer from the git global config environment. There are huge chances that the error message comes from this code path and @msound's comment is spot on!

This is described in the xml documentation of the function

`/// <para>
/// The Committer will be guessed from the Git configuration.
/// An exception will be raised if no configuration is reachable.
/// </para>`

Another **[overload](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp/IRepository.cs#L158-L168)** accepts both the Author and Committer signatures as parameter for a better control of the provided identities.

Comment: Using the overload method solved the problem, thanks!